# Initialize stdin to make Bash script acceptable for multiple stdin input?

Tags: bash

I have a long Bash function, in the script, multiple stdin input can be used. following one is short version of the function.

```
foobar(){
  cat > tmp.sh 
  cp tmp.sh commands.sh  
  // and more scripts here
  // something here to initialize stdin 
  . commands.sh  
  // and more scripts here
}
```

As usage of the function, first you'll send list of commands to file, then evaluate the file as list of commands.
Following one will be successed with no error, but next one will be failed because the one requires confirmation `y` as stdin. I know you can pass a option "-y" to bypass this confirmation but in this case I need versatility.

```
foobar <<< "echo baz"
```

```
foobar <<< "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable"
```

```
After this operation, 795 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

So the function must get at least two stdin, any way to implement this? thanks.

Comment: ? apt-get --yes ?

Comment: ya, I know that. but I I need versatility in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass something as the input of you program:

```
foobar <<< "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable <<<\"y\""
```